# Conditional appending of data to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I am fairly new in Python. I have two pandas data frames `ak12_01` and `T01`

`ak12_01
  objectid, coordID, year, doy
0 495395    5497     2001  120`
and

`T01
  coordID, year,  1,  2,  3, ...
0 5497     2001  249 251 231 ...
1 5498     2001  239 231 251 ...`

I want to add a given value from `T01` to `ak12_01` on two conditions:

1) if `T01['coordID'] == ak12_01['coordID']`

2) if `T01(column name) == ak12_01['doy'].`
In the `T01` dataset, the column names represent the `doy` (day of the year)

I get an error when comparing the '`coordID`' from the two dataset as they are not equally long (*Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects*). Is there a smart way of adding the given value from `T01` to `ak_12_01` based on these to conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it is possible to do by doing the following merge.

1. I transposed the doy data, so it is all in 1 column.
2. merge_ID_doy = ak2012_1.merge(T01, how='inner', left_on=['coordID', 'doy'], right_on=['coordID', 'doy']).

Then it merges all the data with similar doy and coordID with each other.